# sbt run - how to specify working directory?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to run some code using `sbt run` (more precisely, `sbt runMain`) from DIFFERENT directory from where build.sbt resides.

What I have found so far:

- sbt will only work correctly if started from project root directory
- there is no safe way in Java to change working directory
- I probably need to include `fork in run := true` in build.sbt so sbt starts new process with possibly different working directory

So, question is: How to specify working directory for forked process, started by `sbt run`?

Comment: See the duplicate question. You need `fork in run := true` and `baseDirectory in run := file("/path/to/dir")`

Comment: Yep, 
`sbt "set fork in run := true" "set baseDirectory in run := file(\"$HOMEDIR\")" "runMain com.company.MainClass"` works perfectly.